# What is the exact function for n-dimensional perculation problem?

Tags: continuity, percolation

Prepare a 2d tensor with random values from normal distribution.
Let then round these numbers to 0s (white) and 1s (black) depending on the intensity.

Code:

```
m = np.random.rand(size, size)  
m = np.where(m < intensity, 0, 1)
```

Let now count number of clusters that contains 0s and 1s.
I have prepared the code for this problem and the plot looks like:

[image: img]

It seems that 2d white noise can be the most intensive at:
$$x \approx 0.73$$

---

I have found a function for the same problem, but with 1d tensor it is:
$$(1 - x) x$$

See image:
[image: img]

---

For 2d, 3d, ... tensors, I have no idea how to approach this problem.   I also found that it is a problem from percolation theory.

---

How to find ideal function for this problem?